# xcolor error while preparing latex poster

Tags: baposter

I am new to latex and I am trying to prepare a poster in latex using a built in template downloaded from (http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/). I downloaded every package that it asked in errors. Right now I am getting a bunch of errors related to xcolor.sty. Package error: undefined color n'. with some other colors as well. I am using baposter class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal example code, so that we can really understand what is going on. However, it seems to me that you are using some colors which are undefined. You should define it by `\definecolor{}{}{}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code reproducing the error?

Comment: Is this issue solved? How? If not please add an short compilable TeX code resulting in your error to your question. BTW: Is your system up-to-date? There was a bug in `xcolor` with option `table` ...